# How can I attach an attribute to a VinylFS object such that it can be used downstream in the pipeline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to attach an attribute to a VinylFS object in Node. Basically, my module opens a transform stream in object mode, and sets the `_transform` function to add the attribute. (I settled on this method by reading the source of other implementations, notably `gulp-rename` and VinylFS itself.)

However, when I get further downstream in the pipeline, the attribute is undefined. How can I make it so that downstream stream consumers can read my attribute? I'm pretty sure there's a race condition somewhere, especially given the order of the console output, but where it is or why it happens is somewhat beyond me.

Here's the `gulpfile.js` used for testing:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var straticParseHeader = require('./index.js');
var log = require('./log.js');

gulp.task('parse', function() {
    gulp.src('new-blog-new-site.md')
        .pipe(straticParseHeader())
        .pipe(log());
});
```

Here's `index.js` (what I'm really trying to make work):

```
'use strict';

var Stream = require('stream');

function parseHeader(obj) {
    var stream = Stream.Transform({objectMode: true});

    stream._transform = function(file, unused, callback) {
        file.test = 'something';
        console.log(file.test);
        callback(null, file);
    };

    return stream;
};

module.exports = parseHeader;
```

And here's the contents of `log.js` (another test file used to test whether downstream consumers work):

```
module.exports = function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
};
```

And finally, here's the console output:

```
% gulp parse
[10:03:04] Using gulpfile ~/Development/stratic-parse-header/gulpfile.js
[10:03:04] Starting 'parse'...
undefined
[10:03:04] 'parse' errored after 6.14 ms
[10:03:04] TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
    at Transform.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:495:8)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/alex/Development/stratic-parse-header/gulpfile.js:10:4)
    at module.exports (/home/alex/Development/stratic-parse-header/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/alex/Development/stratic-parse-header/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/alex/Development/stratic-parse-header/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/alex/Development/stratic-parse-header/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
something
```

Comment: someone really should come by and delete [tag:gulp] and add [tag:vinylfs], but [tag:gulp] was the closest I could do with my privileges.